# Добавление в середину ArrayList Java - Java SE

Tags: java

У меня есть класс Clerk, в себе он содержит ArrayList объектов типа Supplicant

```
public final class Clerk {
    ArrayList<Supplicant> queueSup = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

в каждого объекта типа Supplicant есть приоритет

```
public class Supplicant {
      int Priority;
}
```

В классе `Clerk` я разрабатываю функцию добавления нового посетителя `Supplicant` в `ArrayList` по приоритету. Т.е при добавлении нового посетителя если у него приоритет выше чем у кого-то из списка, то этот посетитель (которого мы добавляем) встает перед ним.

Например у меня в списке есть Иван с приоритетом 5, Юрий с приоритетом 2, я добавляю Андрея с приоритетом 3, то должно быть: Иван, Андрей, Юрий.

Вот сама функция:

```
public void QueueUp(Supplicant sup_obj){
    int index=0;
    if (queueSup.size() == 0) {
        queueSup.add(sup_obj);
        System.out.println(sup_obj.Name+" самый первый");
    }
    else {
        for (int i=0;i<queueSup.size();++i){
            if (sup_obj.Priority > queueSup.get(i).Priority) {
                index=i;
                System.arraycopy(queueSup, index,  // Компилятор ругаеться на эту строчку
                    queueSup, index+1,
                    queueSup.size() - index);
                queueSup.set(index,sup_obj);
                break;
            }
        } 
        queueSup.add(sup_obj);
    }
}
```

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2):

Все-таки, не "компилятор ругается", а "в процессе выполнения программы, выбрасывается исключение `java.lang.ArrayStoreException`.

Метод `System.arraycopy` не работает с классом `java.util.ArrayList`, а работает только с всевозможными массивами типа `int[]`, `Object[]` и т.п. Входные параметры у него указаны, как `Object`, т.к. в Java пока массивы примитивных типов (`int[]`, `double[]` и прочие) никак не совместимы по типу с массивами объектов (`Object[]`, `String[]`..), но являются объектами. В других местах стандартной библиотеки Java этот вопрос решается кучей перегруженных методов, с аргументами из всевозможных массивов примитивов.

Так же, вы не увеличили размер массива перед копированием хвоста, поэтому даже на нормальном массиве код бы не сработал.

Но вам это все и не нужно, т.к. `ArrayList` может вставить в произвольную позицию со сдвигом хвоста за вас, с помощью метода `add(int index, E element)`:

```
public void QueueUp(Supplicant sup_obj) {
    // специально обрабатывать случай пустой очереди не нужно, 
    // при пустой очереди ни разу не выполнится тело цикла
    for (int i = 0; i < queueSup.size(); ++i) {
        if (sup_obj.Priority > queueSup.get(i).Priority) {
            // добавит новый элемент в позицию i со сдвигом остальных элементов списка
            queueSup.add( i, sup_obj );
            // return вместо break, чтобы не добавить элемент второй раз
            return;
        }
    }
    // добавляем элемент в конец списка
    queueSup.add(sup_obj);
}
```

Если вас интересует только очередь посетителей, можно заменить `ArrayList` на `PriorityQueue` и реализовать для клиента `Comparable<Supplicant>`, но `PriorityQueue` не гарантирует порядок внутри коллекции и при итерировании, только то, что в голове очереди всегда будет наименьший элемент.

Answer (score 0):

Во-первых, ругается вроде как не компилятор. Ругается при выполнении и выкидывает `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayStoreException.`

В-вторых, предположу, что списки откуда копируем и куда копируем наверно желательно чтобы бы ли разными списками а не одним и тем же.

В-третьих, стоит обратиться к документации на [System.arrayCopy](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy(java.lang.Object,%20int,%20java.lang.Object,%20int,%20int))

И пара заметок, так, к слову. 
Наверно лучше все-таки было бы указывать типом для `queueSup` интерфейс `List`, а не готовую реализацию - просто, имхо, правило хорошего тона) (Если конечно вам не понадобятся всякие свои методы из `ArrayList`)

Лучше поля классов делать все-таки наверно приватными - это надежнее. И обращаться к ним через геттеры/сеттеры